# register on a complextype nusoap

Tags: soap, methods, soap-client, nusoap, complextype

I have a problem to pass an Array to my function:
Here the code:

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
'User', 
'complexType', 
'struct', 
'all', 
'', 
    array( 
        'Login'     => array('name'=>'Login','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'Password'  => array('name'=>'Password','type'=>'xsd:string'),
        'Nome'      => array('name'=>'Nome','type'=>'xsd:string'), 
    )
);

$server->register(
  'NewUser', //nome operazione
   array('Login'=>'xsd:string', 
        'Password'=>'xsd:string',

   ),
   array('return'=>'tns:NewUserResponse'), 
   'NewUser'
 );

 function NewUser($Login, $Password) { 
       // my code 
 }
```

So, I don't want pass $Login and $Password but all the array.
I try with:

```
$server->register(
   'NewUser',
    array('new_user' => 'tns:User'),
    array('return'=>'tns:NewUserResponse'), 
    'NewUser'
 );
 function NewUser($new_user) { 
        // my code 
 }
```

With the classical passage of data it works. Anyone have an idea to how can I pass instead the array with all data at my function?
stefy